# How do I change the implementation of a variable in my subclass?

Tags: java, inheritance, collections

In a base class I have a variable implemented as an ArrayList:

```
class Base<E> {

    List<Collection<E>> adj;

    public Base (int size) {
        adj = new ArrayList<Collection<E>>(size);
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            adj.add(new ArrayList<E>());
    }
}
```

Now in a subclass, I want to change the implementation to a HashSet:

```
class Sub<E> extends Base<E> {

    List<Collection<E>> adj;

    public Sub (int size) {
        adj = new ArrayList<Collection<E>>(size);
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            adj.add(new HashSet<E>());
    }
}
```

But it won't let me because it gives me a "Must explicitly evoke another constructor" error.  What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if it tells you to invoke another constructor, you should try invoking another constuctor.

```
public Sub (int size) {
   super(size); // invoke superclass constructor
   adj = new ArrayList<Collection<E>>(size);
   for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   adj.add(new HashSet<E>());
}
```

Yes, I'm aware this is not an ideal solution. I'll revise this when I have time.

Comment: Is it bad that it's initializing `adj` twice?

Comment: Yes it's bad. Doing things twice for no good indicates a bad design. Just provide an empty "protected" no-arg constructor in Base<E>.

There is also no need to redeclare "adj", just make sure it is protected in Base<E>

Comment: Actually "no need" must be the biggest understatement I've read so far today. Shadowing a member is such a likely scenario for bugs that I'm shuddering just thinking about it. Especially unnecessary since a `Collection<E>` will except a hashset just fine!

Comment: This is actually a bad solution. You get rid of the error but your code is bad!

Answer (score 1):

While some people have answered the question, they're missing the larger and more important point: **Don't** ever shadow a member of your base class! There may be one or two rare situations where you have a good reason to do so, but I can't think of any. It's a common beginner mistake though.

To demonstrate the problem easily:

```
private static class Foo {
    protected int x = 1;
}

private static class Bar extends Foo {
    protected int x = 0;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Bar b = new Bar();
    Foo f = b;
    System.out.println(b.x); // prints 0
    System.out.println(f.x); // prints 1
}
```

In your example you really don't want to have two lists in your class with the "same" name that contain different stuff. The solution is easy though: Make the member in the base class protected (otherwise you can only subclass in the same package) and remove the declaration in the child class.

About your constructor problem: That's simple but has two parts: If you don't explicitly write any `super` call in your constructor, the compiler automatically inserts a `super()` call into your code. 
Furthermore if you don't write any constructor of your own the compiler generates a parameter less constructor, as soon as you do though such a constructor is not automatically generated. Since your Base class has a constructor that takes an int, when you don't write the explicit super call the compiler generates a call to `super()` which doesn't exist.

If you write a parameterless constructor in your base class your code would compile and call this one implicitly. That's a bad idea though since you want to let your baseclass know the size the user wants, so what you really want here is call `super(size)`!

Comment: Better than declaring the field protected you should set it as private and provide a protected setter and getter. Due to the fact that you are working with lists the parent class should be the one responsible for filling the list. It may be not a simple asignation

Comment: @iberbeu True, that gives you the usual advantages of abstraction, etc. but I didn't want to make the post even longer by going into that stuff and for internal classes I generally am fine with just accessing protected variables directly, depends how likely the definition is going to change - a list of collections is pretty abstract already though ;)

Answer (score 0):

That's how Java constructs objects. The first thing (after some static initialization stuff) the constructor of the subclass does is construct the superclass. Java does this automatically by calling the default constructor of your superclass. The default constructor is always a constructor with no arguments. So in your case this would have been:

```
public Base() {
  // do construction work here
}
```

Now since your superclass does not have a default constructor Java does not know which constructor to use to construct the superclass.

So **either** you add a default constructor which in turn calls your specialized constructor, like:

```
public Base () {
  this(4); // default value for example
}

public Base (int size) {
   adj = new ArrayList<Collection<E>>(size);
   for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
     adj.add(new ArrayList<E>());
}
```

**Or** you do as @Zong li says, and call your `super(size)` constructor explicitly from within your specialized constructor. Since in this case you want to completely override the constructor, an empty no-arg (default) constructor would be my choice.

Comment: Really **bad** idea to not explicitly call `super(size)` from the constructor that's given a specific size argument. You don't want the base class to assume a size of 4 while the caller explicitly told you to use size 10. Even worse the base class will assume size 4 to setup everything while the super class will work on size 10..

Comment: I agree it is really bad. It was just an example about the possibilities. As said in my answer I would prefer an **empty** default constructor.

Comment: Maybe it's just a misunderstanding with "empty" default constructor, if you mean not providing a default constructor in base or if providing one forwarding `Sub(size)` to `super(size)` then we agree. If you mean just providing an empty Base constructor and not forwarding the Sub constructor to the right base constructor we do disagree, not sure.